# passing cookie data on MeteorJS HTTP request

Tags: meteor, http-headers, httpcookie

It already took me several hours implementing cookie on url MeteorJS. What I need to do is that, pass a cookie data n url like 'CURLOPT_COOKIE' PHP. I cant find any example code on their docs and even to forums. For now I have these functions:

```
/* HTTP REQUEST */
Meteor.methods({
   httpRequest: function(type, uri, params){
    this.unblock();
    check(type, String);
    check(uri, String);
    check(params, Object);
    try {
        var result = HTTP.call(type, uri, {params: params});
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        // Got a network error, time-out or HTTP error in the 400 or 500 range.
        return e;
    }
   }
});
// HTTP request with cooki
 getUserDetails: function(session_id, uid){
  var params = {
     headers: {
      Cookie: {
        sessid: session_i
      }
    },      
    uid: uid
  };
  var response =  Meteor.call('httpRequest', "POST", "http://example.com/rest/wp /alt_wp_resources/loaduser.json", params);
  //res = JSON.parse(response.content);  
  return response;
}
// call here
Meteor.startup(function () {
// delay for 5 sec
Meteor.setTimeout(function (){
    Meteor.call('getUserCredentials', 'api12345', '123qweasd', function (error, result) {                   
    // check user authentication
    var success = result.success;
    console.log(result);
    // user has account from lpgp site, let's save him to meteor.
    if (success){
        console.log('success');
        var session_id = result.session_id;
        //console.log(_session_id);
        Meteor.call('getUserDetails', 'SESSba071091c09f79fefd66e4884dcdde50', 68558, function (error, result) {
            if (!error)
                console.log(result);
            else
                console.log(error);         
        });         
    }else
        // app can't find user account from lpgp site.
        console.log(error);             
});
}, 5000);
});
```

The call is successful but, just returned a success: false.

Response:

```
Object {statusCode: 200, content: "{"success":false}", headers: Object, data: Object}
```

Answer (score 3):

Meteor's HTTP module on the server side is merely a wrapper for the [npm module named `request`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request). The `request` npm module includes support for specifying your own cookies as well as saving them into a cookie jar (just follow the link and search for 'cookie'). The default cookie jar is `tough-cookie` and interestingly, Meteor includes it even though I don't see any way to use it from Meteor.HTTP.

The upshot of these implementation details is that you can use `request` directly. I took a similar approach to wrapping request as Meteor's HTTP module but instead of the restricted sub-set of options that HTTP provides, my wrapper allows full access to all the capability of `request` and `tough-cookie`. The cool part is that you don't even need to directly add `request` as a dependency on your own since it's already a dependency of Meteor. The risk, of course, is that a later version of Meteor could use something besides `request` and your code would break.

Anyway, here is my own wrapper for `request`. It includes an example of JSessionID cookie support for making Jenkins API calls. Just put this into a file `syncRequest.coffee` under the `\server` folder and make sure you have added the `coffeescript` package (`Meteor add coffeescript`)... or compile my code and save it to a .js file in the `\server` folder.

```
request = Npm.require('request')

populateData = (response) ->
  contentType = (response.headers["content-type"] or ";").split(";")[0]
  if _.include([ "application/json", "text/javascript" ], contentType)
    try
      response.data = JSON.parse(response.content)
    catch err
      response.data = null
  else
    response.data = null

normalizeOptions = (uri, options, callback) ->
  unless uri?
    throw new Error("undefined is not a valid uri or options object.")

  if (typeof options is "function") and not callback
    callback = options

  if options and typeof options is "object"
    options.uri = uri
  else if typeof uri is "string"
    options = uri: uri
  else
    options = uri

  return {options, callback}

normalizeResponse = (error, res, body) ->
  response = null
  unless error
    response = {}
    response.statusCode = res.statusCode
    response.content = body
    response.headers = res.headers
    populateData(response)
    if response.statusCode >= 400
      error = makeErrorByStatus(response.statusCode, response.content)
  return {error, response}

wrappedRequest = (uri, options, callback) ->
  {options, callback} = normalizeOptions(uri, options, callback)
  request(options, (error, res, body) ->
    {error, response} = normalizeResponse(error, res, body)
    callback(error, response)
  )

wrappedCall = (method, uri, options, callback) ->
  options.method = method
  wrappedRequest(uri, options, callback)

wrappedGet = (uri, options, callback) -> wrappedCall("GET", uri, options, callback)
wrappedPost = (uri, options, callback) -> wrappedCall("POST", uri, options, callback)
wrappedPut = (uri, options, callback) -> wrappedCall("PUT", uri, options, callback)
wrappedDelete = (uri, options, callback) -> wrappedCall("DELETE", uri, options, callback)

getWithJSession = (j_username, j_password, securityCheckUri, uri, callback) ->
  request = request.defaults({jar: true})

  form = {j_username, j_password}

  request.post({uri: securityCheckUri, form: form}, (error, response, body) ->
    if error?
      throw new Error(error)
    else if response.statusCode isnt 302
      throw new Error("Expected response code 302 (forward). Got #{response.statusCode}")
    else
      request.get(uri, (error, res, body) ->
        {error, response} = normalizeResponse(error, res, body)
        callback(error, response)
      )
  )

syncRequest = Meteor.wrapAsync(wrappedRequest)
syncRequest.call = Meteor.wrapAsync(wrappedCall)
syncRequest.get = Meteor.wrapAsync(wrappedGet)
syncRequest.post = Meteor.wrapAsync(wrappedPost)
syncRequest.put = Meteor.wrapAsync(wrappedPut)
syncRequest.delete = Meteor.wrapAsync(wrappedDelete)
syncRequest.del = syncRequest.delete

syncRequest.getWithJSession = Meteor.wrapAsync(getWithJSession)
syncRequest.getWithJsession = syncRequest.getWithJSession

(exports ? this).syncRequest = syncRequest
```